# How to set a text filter for boost log?

Tags: c++, logging, boost

Starting from a logging set-up with a single logging file, a second logging file should be added containing only the lines with a specific text in the message.

Example:

In the single logging file:

- "user a logged in"
- "user b logged in"
- "user a logged out"

In the second logging file only the messages of user b should be include:

- "user b logged in"

Without the code creating the logging being impacted, example:
`BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "user " << user << " logged in";`

I am searching for a solution which filters on the message in the logging class.
I have got this working, however I do not succeed to get this working with a parameter.

```
        // Main logging file
        g_file_sink = logging::add_file_log
        (
            keywords::file_name = "General.%3N",
            keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%] [%Severity%] %Message%",
            keywords::open_mode = (std::ios::out | std::ios::app),
            keywords::auto_flush = true,
            keywords::rotation_size = 1024,
        );

        // Second logging file

        std::string text = "user a";

        // define the filter
        logging::filter flt =
            []
            (std::string text)
            {
                std::stringstream ss;
                ss << expr::smessage;
                std::string message = ss.str();
                return (message.find(text) == std::string::npos);
            };


        g_file1_sink = logging::add_file_log
        (
            keywords::file_name = test + ".%3N",
            keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%] [%Severity%] %Message%",
            keywords::open_mode = (std::ios::out | std::ios::app),
            keywords::auto_flush = true,
            keywords::filter = flt,
            keywords::rotation_size = 1024,
        );

                // Main filter
        logging::core::get()->set_filter
        (
            logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::warning
        );

        logging::add_common_attributes();
```

When I hardcode the "text"

```
        // define the filter
        logging::filter flt =
            []
            ()
            {
                std::stringstream ss;
                ss << expr::smessage;
                std::string message = ss.str();
                return (message.find("user a") == std::string::npos);
            };
```

It is working as wanted, as soon I add variable text, I am getting a compiler error on the interface.

Is there a way, without have to change the calling code?

Comment: None of this compiles for me. Can you make it selfcontained: https://godbolt.org/z/6GnjKKvfa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot apply filters to log record message text because message text is composed *after* the filtering is done. This is intentional, as this allows to avoid composing the text if the log record is to be discarded anyway.

If you want to filter log records pertaining to a specific user, the way to do this is to use attributes. For example, you can put the user name in a constant attribute and then apply a filter to that attribute. Depending on your code design, the attribute can be added to a logger or to the current thread (e.g. when user-specific activity is confined in a fixed set of threads). You can also use [scoped attributes](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/attributes.html#log.detailed.attributes.related_components.scoped_attributes) if user-specific activity is only performed in a given scope.

```
// Define attribute keyword
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_username, "Username", std::string)

void init_logging()
{
    // Main logging file
    g_file_sink = logging::add_file_log
    (
        keywords::file_name = "General.%3N",
        keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%] [%Severity%] %Message%",
        keywords::open_mode = (std::ios::out | std::ios::app),
        keywords::auto_flush = true,
        keywords::rotation_size = 1024
    );

    // Second logging file
    g_file1_sink = logging::add_file_log
    (
        keywords::file_name = "A.%3N",
        keywords::filter = a_username == "A",
        keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%] [%Severity%] %Message%",
        keywords::open_mode = (std::ios::out | std::ios::app),
        keywords::auto_flush = true,
        keywords::rotation_size = 1024
    );

    // Main filter
    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::warning
    );

    logging::add_common_attributes();
}

int main()
{
    init_logging();

    // Create a logger that will emit log records not related to any specific user
    boost::log::severity_logger< boost::log::trivial::severity_level > lg;
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, boost::log::trivial::warning)
        << "Log record with no username";

    // Create a logger that will emit log records pertaining to user A
    boost::log::severity_logger< boost::log::trivial::severity_level > lg_a;
    lg_a.add_attribute(a_username.get_name(),
        boost::log::attributes::make_constant(std::string("A")));

    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg_a, boost::log::trivial::warning)
        << "Log record related to user A";
}
```

Note that you can use attributes in the formatter as well. This way you could mark all records associated with a given user in the output.

Comment: Hello Andrey,

Thank you fort this answer. I want to filter on a part of a string, so I have to dig a bit deeper in the filtering via Tags to understand this. I saw already a lot of references on the web, but I need some time to figure it out.

Additionally I have see how I can avoid to have separate logging entries for both cases.
Here in your example the main routine calls BOOST_LOG_SERV twice, each with a different severity_logger, but I want to have only 1 in my main code. 
The split up should be done in my logger class.

Comment: @Filip You can use scoped attributes to automatically add/remove the attribute, which will allow you to use a single logger. But I should note that this will incur performance overhead, so having separate loggers is still the preferred approach.